# Connection tab missing in Internet properties

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am experiencing issue with Internet explorer. Connection tab is missing. Looking forward to quick resolution. Machine is connected to the domain.

[image]

Comment: It has been disabled through group policy by your system administrator.

Comment: How can I override this? Any solution via registry editor or else??

Comment: The only solution is to speak to your system administrator.